# TypeScript 1.8 - Why does my React Stateless Function component throw a TypeError at runtime?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tsx

I am attempting to create a [React Stateless Function component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#stateless-functions) as described in the TypeScript 1.8 [release notes](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript).
This compiles without error but throws a `TypeError` at runtime.
Why?

I have an interface

```
interface AppError {
  id: string;
  message: string;
}
```

My component looks like this:
    import * as React from "react";

```
import { AppError } from "../error.interface";

const ErrorMessage = (props: {key: string, error: AppError}) => (
  <div className="col-lg-12" id={this.props.error.id}>
    <h2 className="page-header"><small>{this.props.error.message}</small>  </h2>
  </div>
);

export default ErrorMessage;
```

It is used from another component like this:

```
import * as React from "react";

import * as ErrorModel from "./../error.model";
import { AppError } from "./../error.interface";

import ErrorMessage from "./error.message.tsx";


export default class ErrorContainer extends React.Component<{}, ErrorContainerState> {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
      this.state = this._buildState();
    }

    componentDidMount() { ErrorModel.observable.addListener(this._onModelUpdate.bind(this)); }
    componentWillUnmount() { ErrorModel.observable.removeListener(this._onModelUpdate.bind(this)); }

    render() {
        let divStyle = {
            marginTop: "15px"
        };

        return (
           <div className="row" id="errors" style={divStyle}>
                {this.state.errors.map((e) => <ErrorMessage key={e.id} error={e} />)}
           </div>
            );
    }

    _onModelUpdate() {
        this.setState(this._buildState());
    }

    _buildState() {
        return {
            errors: ErrorModel.getErrors()
        };
    }
}

interface ErrorContainerState {
    errors: AppError[];
}
```

This compiles without error. However, at runtime I get the error: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'error' of undefined(…)`. The error is pointing to the line in my stateless function:
`<div className="col-lg-12" id={this.props.error.id}>`

The full stack trace is below.

This all worked perfectly fine as a normal component.

Version information: Typescript 1.8.7, react 0.14.7

My `react.d.ts` is installed via [typings](https://github.com/typings/typings) and it appears to be the latest.

The full TypeError stack trace:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'error' of
>   undefined(…)ErrorMessage @
>   error.message.tsx:6ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent @
>   ReactCompositeComponent.js:148wrapper @
>   ReactPerf.js:66ReactReconciler.mountComponent @
>   ReactReconciler.js:37ReactMultiChild.Mixin._mountChildByNameAtIndex @
>   ReactMultiChild.js:474ReactMultiChild.Mixin._updateChildren @
>   ReactMultiChild.js:378ReactMultiChild.Mixin.updateChildren @
>   ReactMultiChild.js:326ReactDOMComponent.Mixin._updateDOMChildren @
>   ReactDOMComponent.js:871ReactDOMComponent.Mixin.updateComponent @
>   ReactDOMComponent.js:700ReactDOMComponent.Mixin.receiveComponent @
>   ReactDOMComponent.js:645ReactReconciler.receiveComponent @
>   ReactReconciler.js:87ReactCompositeComponentMixin._updateRenderedComponent
>   @
>   ReactCompositeComponent.js:562ReactCompositeComponentMixin._performComponentUpdate
>   @
>   ReactCompositeComponent.js:544ReactCompositeComponentMixin.updateComponent
>   @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:473wrapper @
>   ReactPerf.js:66ReactCompositeComponentMixin.performUpdateIfNecessary @
>   ReactCompositeComponent.js:421ReactReconciler.performUpdateIfNecessary
>   @ ReactReconciler.js:102runBatchedUpdates @
>   ReactUpdates.js:129Mixin.perform @ Transaction.js:136Mixin.perform @
>   Transaction.js:136assign.perform @
>   ReactUpdates.js:86flushBatchedUpdates @ ReactUpdates.js:147wrapper @
>   ReactPerf.js:66Mixin.closeAll @ Transaction.js:202Mixin.perform @
>   Transaction.js:149ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.batchedUpdates @
>   ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.js:62enqueueUpdate @
>   ReactUpdates.js:176enqueueUpdate @
>   ReactUpdateQueue.js:24ReactUpdateQueue.enqueueSetState @
>   ReactUpdateQueue.js:190ReactComponent.setState @
>   ReactComponent.js:65ErrorContainer._onModelUpdate @
>   error.container.tsx:32(anonymous function) @
>   observable-factory.ts:21arrayEach @ lodash.js:483forEach @
>   lodash.js:7827notifyAll @ observable-factory.ts:21setErrors @
>   error.model.ts:38report @ error.model.ts:15report @
>   error.service.ts:5_handleError @ session.service.ts:34

Comment: Bjorn's answer below is correct. Unfortunately, the reason you don't see a compilation error is because `this` is currently `any` for functions. They're working on fixing this and providing the ability to specify the type of `this`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stateless components don't have `this`.

Change this line:
`<h2 className="page-header"><small>{this.props.error.message}</small>  </h2>`

to

`<h2 className="page-header"><small>{props.error.message}</small>  </h2>`

Comment: Spot on. Just a minor : both for `id` and `message` 

Answer (score 2):

The answer from Björn is the right one (stateless components don't have *this*), just placing here the corrected stateless component code for the sake of clarity:

```
import { AppError } from "../error.interface";

const ErrorMessage = (props: {key: string, error: AppError}) => (
  <div className="col-lg-12" id={props.error.id}>
    <h2 className="page-header"><small>{props.error.message}</small>  </h2>
  </div>
);

export default ErrorMessage;
```